# Listening for properties in different class

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to invoke an event every time a property (boolean) is changed. There is the INotifyPropertyChanged interface but it works with properties you write yourself. I have a tcp socket with the Connected property. Currently I am using a while-loop to check the connection state but I want to know if there is a way to handle this with events.

ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the underlying class does not support it, there is not a way of monitoring for change of a class property.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option would be to create a derived class like this:

```
    public class MySocket : System.Net.Sockets.Socket, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private bool _connected = false;
        private Thread _pollingThread;

        public new bool Connected
        {
            get { return _connected; }
            private set { _connected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public MySocket() : base (System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
        {
            _pollingThread = new Thread(PollingThread);
            _pollingThread.IsBackground = true;
            _pollingThread.Start();
        }

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void PollingThread()
        {
            while (true) {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                if (base.Connected != Connected) Connected = base.Connected;
            }
        }            
    }
```

This is just an untested example to give you a general idea of what *could* be done.

This class will start a separate `Thread` which verifies the state of the `Connected` Property of its base class every 500ms. Once the state changes the `Connected` Property of the child class is updated using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.

Is this a good idea? That really depends on what you are doing, threads are rather resource intensive, especially when they are created. This could quickly become a relevant waste of resources. You probably can achieve what you are trying to do by re-thinking your approach.

Comment: This code might not behave as expected - it could easily miss a transition from True to False and back to True again. If the state change was permanent (i.e. True to False could never transition back to True) then this notifies that the property HAD changed not that it HAS changed - i.e. it has an inherent delay; which could itself be problematic.

A nice comprehensive answer - but wanted to point out the limitations of the method.

Comment: @PhillipH, true, this approach is far from a solution. In fact I upvoted your answer, since I agree that it cannot/shouldn't be done. I just wanted to provide a workaround that might be used to provide some sort of status feedback to the user. The code can surely be improved to become a bit more reliable, at least for the purpose of the earlier described scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try/follow the observer/ observable pattern...